Has Japanese always used negative constructions for obligation?
Interestingly enough, most languages I know use a direct construction to express obligation: "You must do something.", "You ought to do it." Japanese is different in that regard with constructions such as なくてはならない, なければならない, and so on. Was it always like this? Is this the result of Japanese culture and potentially of (neo-)Confucian values or can we not draw any such conclusion? This discusses the origins of なければならない and such but they don't discuss if there was something older used for expressing obligation.

This is not a double negative in the sense people normally mean, as in one verb negated multiple times

Sorry, good point I will rephrase this.

As mentioned in the thread you linked to, ～なければならない came into being pretty recently.In the Heian/classical period (IX/XIII centuries) obligation/duty (当然・義務) was expressed thru the modal adjective べし. This is the ancestor of the modern べく・べき. For example, in Taketori monogatari (月見, line 1000 or whereabouts), Kaguyahime tells us:

さらずまかりぬべければ
"Since I must go [back] without fail..."

Which would be roughly equivalent to today's いかなければならない.
However,  べし has many uses. It can also express supposition、intention or possibility. So it's definitely less clear cut than the idiom なければならない.
As for the philosophical underpinnings...At least in this case, the adoption of べし seems to have more to do with usage than ideology. A popular theory traces it back to 宜し【うべし】, which means "very true, certainly so". This eventually took on the nuance of "it must be so", from which the "obligation" usage emerged.
Also, there probably are more ways to express obligation in classsical japanese. I just wasn't able to find them. This is probably even more true of the language after the XIII century, when the evolution towards Edo period Japanese started.   It's reasonable to assume that in this transition other expressions became more popular than べし. However, I don't know much of the grammar and linguistic history of this period.

Thank you for the explanation, do you know if we have knowledge of anything similar closer to Old Japanese?

The equivalent of ～ないといけない in classical Japanese is ～ざるべからず. It was common, but I'm not sure if it was as common as ～ないといけない.

@Saegusa Suffix described in this answer and original adjective and adverb are also attested in Old Japanese (8th century). Vovin (2020, page 784): "The debitive suffix -umbɛ- appears extremely rarely in the earliest Western Old Japanese texts: it is found once in the Kojiki kayō and once in the Nihonshoki kayō. This should come as no surprise, since -umbɛ- is certainly a grammaticalized form of the adjective umbɛ- ‘to be proper, to be indeed’ or the adverb umbɛ ‘indeed,’ both of which are attested independently in Western Old Japanese texts." (/ɛ/ is his reconstruction for /e2/.)

Fantastic, thank you @Arfrever.
